# Message Interpolate not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to setup an API with validation taking place at the point of mapping request to my Data Transfer Object. I'm having an issue with Interpolate my database driven Message Source. The records within my DB have placeholders:

```
 id,oplock,code,msg,locale
 9,0,minmax_password,"Password length should be a minimum of {1} and maximum of {2}.","en"
```

I have this Data Transfer Object (that should mapped to my request) with this property:

```
@NotBlank(message = "{notnull_password}")
@Size(min = 6, max = 20,message = "{minmax_password}")
private String password;
```

This is my XML setup:

```
 <beans:bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="validationMessageSource" ref="messageSourceServiceImp"/>
</beans:bean>

 <mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator">
 </mvc:annotation-driven>
```

I removed the MessageSource implementation for brevity but, as mentioned it's database driven. Now when I submit a request with `Password` not meeting the minimum requirement, it throws an error and the MessageSource is called, which returns the record...so far so good. What I'm observing is that it subsequently calls the MessageSource for `{1}`  (which is the placeholder from the MessageSource's record); I was thinking this would be replaced by the `min` from the declaration `@Size(min = 6, max = 20,message = "{minmax_password}")`. As a result, this gets returned:

```
      "Password length should be a minimum of {1} and maximum of {2}."
```

Let me know if I'm missing anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hibernte Validator doesn't seem to uses numeric indices **{1}, {2}, etc**. Therefore, I'd have to use **{min},{max}**. Also for database driven MessageSource, it usually returns a MessageFormat object. This object expects numeric indices and not text. Using **{min}** throws a NumberFormatException because, it can't parse `min`. As a result, what you have to do is put **{min}** in single quotes; this will tell MessageFormat to ignore that section. Example:

```
 9,0,minmax_password,"Password length should be a minimum of '{min}' and maximum of '{max}'.","en"
```

Hope this helps.